# Disk size does not match at all (ubuntu/VMWare)

Tags: partitioning, vmware, disk-usage

I setup a ubuntu server on VMWare with 50GB.

Now my ubuntu says I don't have enough space. `df -h` indeed tells me my ubuntu only has 24G...

```
buzz@plex-vm:~$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              391M   17M  375M   5% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   24G   24G     0 100% /
tmpfs                              2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop1                         183M  183M     0 100% /snap/microk8s/2407
/dev/loop2                          71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21029
/dev/loop3                          33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12704
/dev/sda2                          976M  107M  803M  12% /boot
tmpfs                              391M     0  391M   0% /run/user/1000
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/51409ef32a730a343a26395556584edd5bd17873c10109d3a6fa1a4d3c911141/shm
overlay                             24G   24G     0 100% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/51409ef32a730a343a26395556584edd5bd17873c10109d3a6fa1a4d3c911141/rootfs
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/b61c7a372768621c65b2df55294be4349f2390ec6638189a5fcc95e2c859427e/shm
overlay                             24G   24G     0 100% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/b61c7a372768621c65b2df55294be4349f2390ec6638189a5fcc95e2c859427e/rootfs
overlay                             24G   24G     0 100% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/07426bdff7fccf7e772ca7f89044ab2802f6fe223feb23756118c30969610d0b/rootfs
overlay                             24G   24G     0 100% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/823bca245e00413131fb57eb002442e288cde003bd6556dd50a306229cfa74e1/rootfs  

buzz@plex-vm:~$ sudo parted
GNU Parted 3.3
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p
Model: VMware, VMware Virtual S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 53.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  1076MB  1074MB  ext4
 3      1076MB  53.7GB  52.6GB
```

vgdisplay gives me the following:

```
buzz@plex-vm:~$ sudo vgdisplay
--- Volume group ---
VG Name               ubuntu-vg
System ID
Format                lvm2
...
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
...
VG Size               <49.00 GiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              12543
Alloc PE / Size       6272 / 24.50 GiB
Free  PE / Size       6271 / <24.50 GiB
...
```

But when I try to extend it says there's no space left on disk, no matter how much I want to extend it by...

```
buzz@plex-vm:~$ sudo lvextend -L +2G /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
/etc/lvm/archive: mkdir failed: No space left on device

buzz@plex-vm:~$ sudo lvextend -L +24G /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
/etc/lvm/archive: mkdir failed: No space left on device

buzz@plex-vm:~$ sudo lvextend -l+100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
/etc/lvm/archive: mkdir failed: No space left on device
```

And cfdisk gives me the following:

```
                                                      Disk: /dev/sda
                                Size: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
                           Label: gpt, identifier: 4852B6EA-3BC7-4801-9D11-CED0A0B14B73

Device                           Start                 End             Sectors          Size Type
/dev/sda1                         2048                4095                2048            1M BIOS boot                    /dev/sda2                         4096             2101247             2097152            1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3                      2101248           104855551           102754304           49G Linux filesystem
```

My SSD, which the VM is on, has more than enough free space and in Windows the whole SSD is one partition.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It looks as though when you created your logical volume group, you created it as not the full disk space available.  This was answered in [this answer], which is unfortunately a trivial link to [https://www.linuxtechi.com/extend-lvm-partitions/](https://www.linuxtechi.com/extend-lvm-partitions/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I updated my post to state what happens when trying to do what is described in the link.

Comment: I'm not really conversant with LV's, as I don't actually have a reason to use them on my laptop.  I would check the output of `lvs -a`, to see if this has perhaps been setup as two logical volumes in a mirror arrangement?

Answer (score 2):

Well I managed to get it to extend the LV with

`lvextend -l+100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv -A n` :)

It was the autobackup that blocked the LV to extend because it was so full. So `-A n` sets the autobackup to no in case somebody encounters the same problem.